# Queries per second avg

Tags: mysql

I have Installed MySQL Server 5.6.23 on Centos server and the configuration of the server is

16 GB RAM
8 Core
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit

When I check the status of the server it is showing me **Queries per second avg: 22112.191**

[image]

Still my server is running fine and there is no issue in read & write operation but I would like to know what is the maximum Queries per second my server can handle and what can I do to reduce it.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

22K QPS is nice; I rarely see that high a number on a production system.  You must be doing rather trivial queries.  (In a quick survey, 7K is the 90th percentile.)

Do you use a lot of Stored Routines?  What is your Questions/Uptime?

It is unlikely that a high query rate will "crash" MySQL.  It can slow things down to the point where it feels "crashed".

How many active connections do you have?  When `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show more than a few dozen queries running (not "Sleep") at a time, you are threatening to get in this overburdened situation.

There have been benchmarks (carefully designed) that registered more than a million queries per second.  I could devise a situation that could saturate all the system resources, yet achieve only 1 query per minute.  Those extremes indicate that there are a lot of factors going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply., Yes we are using Stored Routines for most of the cases, Question: 21244778510 & Up Time: 1293967. In my process list I found only 40 connection and most of them are in sleep state

Comment: thanks. Can you provide more details about your statement "(In a quick survey, 7K is the 90th percentile.)" Our DBs (DBaaS) running at 1K QPS. Does that mean we have small deployments?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov - 1K QPS is about the 80th percentile.  That is, your system is busier than most of the 116 that I polled.  As for "small", there are many other factors -- dataset size, complexity of queries, etc.  1K may _or may not_ be so busy that you are having performance problems.  For more analysis, see [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis) .

Answer (score 1):

There's no silver bullet to tell you how many queries per second can you process. You can set up different benchmarks to try to estimate. A 'good enough' approach is to [register the queries with tcpdump](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html) and replay them from external server(s) from multiple parallel threads. You can also play with the concurrency. Register the query response time and plot it as the function of queries / second. When response time is above acceptable threshold that's your maximum queries / seconds for specific concurrency level. I wrote a script some time ago to do the same thing with HTTP requests (the collection is not part of it) and report maximum requests / second: https://github.com/charlesnagy/web-toolkit/blob/master/captest/wt-capacity-test.py It shouldn't be hard to translate to mysql queries.

If you use replication to balance reads you can also start reducing the number of slaves until the query response time is above the threshold and check then the current query rate is your limit.

You can only reduce the number queries if you change the application that sending those queries. Introducing caching, rewriting queries, etc. There are plethora of options but that really depends on your case. Maybe it's completely valid from your application to send that amount of queries and you just need to scale up or out your infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just wanted to know did these much query can crash my database any time due to high number of query per second.?

Comment: @user2173561 maybe most of your queries are really fast. Try checking `show processlist;` periodically during different times of day to see if there are many concurrent connections or even many queries running at the same time. If it stays relatively empty then it should be no problem.

Comment: If you have monitoring then keep an eye on the `thread_running` status variables. This is the concurrent connections @jkavalik mentions. If this value doesn't spike and stays under a reasonable level (the same order of magnitude as CPU cores you have) you will have no problem.

Comment: 40K opens in 2 hours is very high.  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%open%'` for further advice.